# Sharepoint 2010 - Client Object Model Upload content to document library

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepointdocumentlibrary, sharepoint-clientobject

I have the following requirement:

I have created a Flash application that is embedded in a Sharepoint Application Page.  In the Flash application I have to upload text (I cannot create a file on the client side without prompting the user, so I just have to upload the content in plain text) to a document library of the user's choice.

When the text is uploaded (as a .url file), I have to redirect the browser to the edit form that is associated with the library (or more specific with the content type of the new item).

How can I upload content (plain text) as a new document to a Document library using the Client Object Model?

Kind regards,

Karel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload files to SharePoint using the Client Object Model's FileCreationInformation class which has a Content property that is a byte array.

You might use it like so:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(webUrl);
Web web = clientContext.Web;
List documentLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(localFile);
newFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(localFile);

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = documentLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
```